# Redis Sentinel - K8S Bitnami Helm Chart - External Access

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, redis-sentinel

I am trying to deploy a Redis Sentinel deployment on K8s using Bitnami's [helm](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/redis/README.md) chart.
I need access to Redis from outside the K8s cluster which makes it more difficult.
I've set up a LoadBalancer for the redis service but I don't have any control on which sentinels I reach (lb forwards it to a pod) and same for the master/replicas.
So when the sentinel gives me the internal host of the master, I have no way of getting it's external host. All I can do is pass through the load balancer but it might forward my request to a replica and not the master, so I won't be able to write data.

I feel like the solution is to somehow split the service into multiple services where each master/replica is a separate service.
And then every service will have it's own LoadBalancer / NodePort.
Is this possible to accomplish with bitnami's chart?
Or is there another way of accomplishing access to a sentinel redis deployment from outside the k8s cluster?